# Rhythmbox tags: retag or synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the parent site there are currently 3 questions tagged with [rythmbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rythmbox) and 3 questions tagged with [rhythmbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/rhythmbox). In general, I would say that the former questions should be retagged in favour of the correct spelling. However, this appears to be a very common slip (and is very easy to do in this case) so I am wondering if anyone else thinks a tag synonym might be useful instead?

Comment: The choice isn't one or the other: you can do both adding a synonym and retagging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I would say: Fix it.

I don't think we should lower the quality of the site. Anybody who can, should fix typos when they see them be they typos in tags, titles or posts (even answers).

Comment: I can, so I did. Hope that doesn't invalidate the discussion.

Comment: I don't think it invalidates the discussion. Thanks for fixing the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has fixed the rythmbox tags.